# Scaling up number of pipelines AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, umbraco

We have a problem with scaling up in our CI/CD environment.

We have an single Umbraco site that is deployed for almost 200 different customers, with a different look and feel in each case. To keep things as simple as possible, it was decided to keep a single codebase so all deployments are done from the same branch of the same repo. Each customer will have a Azure build and an Azure release pipeline.

We have disabled automatic build, since this would have triggered all the pipelines to run every time a commit was pushed. In order to be flexible with deployments, we added Git tags as triggers in the build pipeline in a format like xxxx_v* and all_v*. This allows us to trigger one specific build, a number of specific builds or all the build pipelines at once. The issue we are having is that the system is becoming cumbersome as more pipelines for more customers are added which causes developers to search for the latest Git tag.

Could there be  another way around these problems? We need to have the ability to trigger any specific pipeline or any group of pipelines or all pipelines at once.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your pipeline & agent configuration? And when you say cumbersome, are you referring to the sheer volume of individual pipelines that you're managing?

Comment: I think you need to pay for more agents. Apart of that. If the code is the same, the build pipelines are the same, and the only one difference is the release target. Then I suggest to have the sites as diferent stages and then manually deploy the artifact resulted of the build pipeline. I mean, just one build pipeline, one release pipeline and several stages to deploy manually. Apart of that, as @MaxMorrow mentioned, more information would be necessay to help you in a better way.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. To be more specific, when I say cumbersome, yes, I mean the sheer number of individual pipelines. It's already difficult for the release team to find the right pipeline and use the git tags system I came up with.                                                              I was asking if anyone has had the same issues and if maybe a different architecture would be more suitable? Especially considering that the release team is not strong on the technical side.